# Grab File From Address Using hostname

Tags: javascript

I'm not quite clear on how to properly ask this question.

I'm using an existing script and trying to customize it so that people don't have to enter the URL to the domain manually using: `window.location.hostname`.

Original code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://enter-your-domain.com/feeds/comments/default?alt=json&max-results=5"></script>
```

So here is what I tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var getDomain = '<script type="text/javascript" src="http//' + window.location.hostname + '/feeds/comments/default?alt=json&max-results=5"></script>';
 return getDomain
</script>
```

I can't quite grasp how to get this to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

You are nesting script tag twice, just use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var getDomain = "http//" + window.location.hostname + '/feeds/comments/default?alt=json&max-results=5'
 return getDomain
</script>
```

Comment: It's output is "' return getDomain". Error console: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL "